# Windows 7 windows firewall updates error

Tags: windows, firewall, updates

I'm having a issue with windows firewall.

I can't turn it on or off. I also can't edit it. And Windows firewall is requesting updates, but whenever I make those updates it still doesn't work.

Here's a pic, but everything is in lithuanian.

[image: http://prntscr.com/3msagh]

Comment: what if you try turning it off and on from command line. any error? maybe this command  `netsh advfirewall set AllProfiles state on `

Comment: It say's An error occurred :(

Comment: That is good. hopefully it's the right command I can't test it from here But Now copy and paste the exact error it gives. that is important. word for word. letter for letter. give a screenshot

Comment: An Error occured while attempting to contact the Windows Firewall service. Make sure that the service is running and try your request again.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Windows Firewall service is not running. To start it, open Control Panel -> Administration Tools -> Services. There find Windows Firewall(it will be translated to lithuanian), right click it and select Start.

Comment: When i press start it say's: Windows could not start the Windows firewall on Local Computer. For more information, review the System event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error Code 5

Comment: @Aurimas Try repairing with this program http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html